# Select a distinct row

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL table:

```
o_id | Salesperson |   fax   | Pincode  
1      Sandy         2110271   12011
2      Sandy         2452356   24523
3      Ricky         1023564   45510
```

I need to get the following result:

```
Salesperson |   fax   | Pincode  
Sandy         2452356   24523
Ricky         1023564   45510
```

(Note: I don't need o_id column to be displayed)

I have tried:

```
select distinct salesperson,faxno,pin 
from OPPORTUNITY
```

and:

```
select salesperson,faxno,pincode 
from OPPORTUNITY 
Group By (salesperson)
```

...but still I am getting:

```
Salesperson |   fax   | Pincode  
Sandy         2110271   12011
Ricky         1023564   45510
```

I have tried a lot of scenarios present on the web but still not able to achieve the expected result.

Is there any property or function that will give "Sandy" -  whose `o_id` is max.

Example:

```
Select distinct sales, faxno, pincode 
from opportunity where o_id= max(o_id)
```

Although above code is not working, but anything like that can help?

Comment: This is a [_groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned query helped me to achieve the following result in the output:

```
Salesperson |   fax   | Pincode  
Sandy         2452356    24523
Ricky         1023564    45510
```

The query is:

```
SELECT x.salesperson, x.fax, x.pincode from opportunity 
as x join (
select max(o_id) as o_id, salesperson from opportunity 
group by salesperson
) as y 
on x.o_id = y.o_id and x.salesperson = y.salesperson
```

Answer (score 7):

The row:

```
Sandy         2452356   24523
```

is preferred because it has the largest `o_id`. You can pick the largest `o_id` per salesperson via:

```
select max(o_id), salesperson
from T 
group by salesperson
```

An important property of SQL is that it is closed, i.e. a result of a query is a relation (table). So we can simply join this with the original table:

```
select x.o_id, x.Salesperson, x.fax, x.Pincode
from T as x
join (
    select max(o_id) as o_id, salesperson
    from T
    group by salesperson
) as y
    on x.o_id = y.o_id
   and x.salesperson = y.salesperson
```

Even if question does not say so explicitly, there is reason to believe that `salesperson` is functionally dependent of `o_id`. If that is the case it is sufficient to join by `o_id` alone:

```
select x.o_id, x.Salesperson, x.fax, x.Pincode
from T as x
join (
    select max(o_id) as o_id, salesperson
    from T
    group by salesperson
) as y
    on x.o_id = y.o_id
```

In SQL2003, window functions were introduced. They are a perfect fit for this kind of query. I have heard the next version of MySQL will support them, but I guess you are not using that.

You also mention this construction:

```
select salesperson,faxno,pincode 
from OPPORTUNITY 
Group By salesperson
```

It is probably the construction in MySQL that causes the most confusion. It is invalid in most (all?) other products, because the result is non-deterministic or random. What happens is that MySQL randomly picks a `faxno, pincode` for each `salesperson`.

Comment: I don't want to display "o_id" column in the output so can you suggest any queries related to this

Comment: Are you asking on how to remove o_id from the result of the query?

Comment: yes, I don't want o_id column to be displayed in the output

Comment: Can you identify where o_id in the result is located in the query? Have you tried removing it?

Comment: In the 1st line (i.e. select command line) of every query, you have used o_id along with Salesman, faxno, pincode. Which will lead to display o_id in the output result. I tried to remove o_id from the select command line but then query is not working.

Comment: That should work, what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Thanks the following code worked: SELECT x.salesperson, x.fax, x.pincode from opportunity as x join (select max(o_id) as o_id, salesperson from opportunity group by salesperson) as y on x.o_id = y.o_id and x.salesperson = y.salesperson

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this using `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()`

```
SELECT  Salesperson,fax,Pincode
FROM    (
    SELECT  Salesperson,fax,Pincode,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Salesperson ORDER BY o_id DESC) AS [ROW_NUMBER]
    FROM    OPPORTUNITY
)   T   
WHERE   [ROW_NUMBER]    =   1
```

Comment: There is no ROW_NUMBER() function in MySQL. This is a MySQL question, not Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

Comment: MariaDB, however, does [support window functions since version 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions-overview/).